# jquery scroll based animation

Tags: jquery

It is difficult to animate on scrolling time. I have searched in internet, but the codes are very difficult to understand, scroll based animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) to reveal [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) based animations. Just add "wow" followed by animation name to the class of the div to be animated. Follow this snippet:

```css
p{
  margin:40px auto;
  padding:100px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  }

.col-1{
  background:orange;
}

.col-2{
  background:green;
  }

.col-3{
  background:blue;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.js"></script>

<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>

<div class="col-1 wow bounceInUp">  
<p>Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-2 wow slideInLeft">  
<p>It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts-Exchange.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-3 fadeInRight">  
<p>The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have created a div I'd (#p_box) and I have called them three times. The code listed below

Comment: <div id="p_box"></div> I want to animate this div when scrolling the page.

Comment: wow.js is built to reveal animations on scroll.Please put your whole code in a snippet or a fiddle to help you.

Comment: <script>
;(function($, win) {
  $.fn.inViewport = function(cb) {
     return this.each(function(i,el){
       function visPx(){
         var H = $(this).height(),
             r = el.getBoundingClientRect(), t=r.top, b=r.bottom;
         return cb.call(el, Math.max(0, t>0? H-t : (b<H?b:H)));  
       } visPx();
       $(win).on("resize scroll", visPx);
     });
  };
}(jQuery, window));



$(".p_set").inViewport(function(px){
    if(px) $(this).addClass("triggeredCSS3") ;

});
</script>

Comment: and the html is 

<div class="p_set translate">
 

 <table name="portfolio_show">
 <tr><td>
 <div id="p_box" data-when="span"
      data-from="0"
      data-to="1"
      data-easing="easeinout"
      data-rotatey="360" ></div></td>
 <td><div id="p_box"  ></div></td>
 <td><div id="p_box" ></div></td></tr>
 

 
 <tr><td><div id="p_box" > </div></td>
 <td><div id="p_box" ></div></td>
 <td><div id="p_box" ></div></td>
 </tr></table>

 </div>


   </div>
          </div>

 </div>

Comment: this jquery code makes scrolling animation only once.